# Read/write XML file preserving original attribute order

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am using `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` to parse an existing XML file and get an instance of `org.w3c.dom.Document`.

After manipulations on this instance, i need to write it back to file. Therefore how can I write `org.w3c.dom.Document` object to XML file using `XMLStreamWriter`?

PS: I am asking this, because I think I need to use `XMLStreamWriter` in order to write the XML file without losing attribute orders.  Attribute orders are important because in the version tree, because of attribute order changes, i don't want to see XML file changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Attribute order is insignificant**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-starttags) per the [**XML Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/):

> Note that the order of attribute specifications in a start-tag or
>   empty-element tag is not significant.

**Therefore, XMLStreamWriter provides no way to constrain attribute ordering.**

In general, the XML recommendations will all consider attribute ordering to be insignificant, but see the [**section on attribute processing**](http://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/#sec-Attribute-processing) in the [**XML Normalization Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/) or the [**Canonical XML Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) if your application has a need for attribute ordering.